# ASN1 decoder (libtasn1-3.3) to print the content of a DD certificate pem

Tags: java, c++, c, encoding, certificate

How Can I Use the ASN1 decoder (libtasn1-3.3) to print the content of a DD certificate pem received as parameter?

Comment: Did [asn1Decoding](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtasn1/manual/libtasn1.html#Invoking-asn1Decoding) fail?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I wasn't aware of this function can you please generate an example?

Comment: Eliot can you still show me how?

Answer (score 0):

asn1Decoding is a program from [libtasn1-3.3](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/general/libtasn1.html)

If that program works for you, then the ansn1Decoding has a decode function which you can use (of course you have to adapt this code out. If you don't want to modify by moving the decode code out to your program, then you have to replicate the decode code into your code):

`static int
decode (asn1_node definitions, const char *typeName, void *der, int der_len,
    int benchmark)`

If you want to call the decoding from your program, then you have to

```
asn1_node definitions = NULL;
int asn1_result = ASN1_SUCCESS;
unsigned char *der;
int der_len = 0, benchmark = 0;
// Please test with asn1Decoding application manually to find the correct typeName for your code
char typeName[] = {"PKIX1.Certificate"};

asn1_result = asn1_parser2tree ("Your File Name", &definitions, errorDescription);
if (asn1_result != ASN1_SUCCESS) {    exit(1); }
{
    size_t tmplen;
    der = (unsigned char *) read_binary_file (inputFileDerName, &tmplen);
    der_len = tmplen;
}

if (der == NULL)
{
      asn1_delete_structure (&definitions);
      exit (1);
}

if (decode (definitions, typeName, der, der_len, benchmark) != ASN1_SUCCESS)
{
      asn1_delete_structure (&definitions);
}
```